# C# - Audit Log - How to get the PK name from model designed in Fluent Api?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to get the primary key name in a model, but my database is designed in Fluent Api and all examples I found are designed in DataAnnotation.

I'm overriding SaveChanges() of DbContext to create an Audit Log.

this is the code to save the audit log.

```
private List<AuditLogModel> GetAuditRecordsForChange(DbEntityEntry dbEntry, int? id_usuario = null)
    {
        List<AuditLogModel> result = new List<AuditLogModel>();

        DateTime changeTime = DateTime.Now;

        // Get the Table() attribute, if one exists
        TableAttribute tableAttr = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault() as TableAttribute;

        // Get table name (if it has a Table attribute, use that, otherwise get the pluralized name)
        string tableName = tableAttr != null ? tableAttr.Name : dbEntry.Entity.GetType().Name;

        // Get primary key value (If you have more than one key column, this will need to be adjusted)
        //string keyName = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties().Single(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), false).Count() > 0).Name;
        var oc = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
        EntityKey key = oc.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(dbEntry.Entity).EntityKey;
        string keyName = key.EntitySetName;

        if (dbEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            // For Inserts, just add the whole record
            // If the entity implements IDescribableEntity, use the description from Describe(), otherwise use ToString()
            result.Add(new AuditLogModel()
            {
                Id_Usuario = id_usuario,
                Id_Registro = (int)dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(keyName),  // Again, adjust this if you have a multi-column key
                EventoTipo = "I", // INSERT
                Tabela = tableName,
                NovoValor = dbEntry.CurrentValues.ToObject().ToString()
            });
            //NovoValor = (dbEntry.CurrentValues.ToObject() is IDescribableEntity) ? (dbEntry.CurrentValues.ToObject() as IDescribableEntity).Describe() : dbEntry.CurrentValues.ToObject().ToString()
        }

        // Otherwise, don't do anything, we don't care about Unchanged or Detached entities

        return result;
    }
```

Look to the ID_Registro property, this receives the ID of the operation.
In this line, keyName needs to specify the name of the primary key field.
And the line will result in an ID that is saved.
But this field is giving error because the primary key is not found.

How can I solve this?

**EDIT:**

This is the model. *Codigo* is the Primary Key.

```
public sealed class AcessoLogModel
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public int CodigoUsuario { get; set; }
    public UsuarioModel Usuario { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public DateTime Horario { get; set; }
}
```

this is the mapping:

```
public AcessoLogMapping()
    {
        ToTable("TB_ACESSO_LOG");
        HasKey(x => x.Codigo);

        Property(x => x.Codigo).HasColumnName("ID_ACESSO_LOG")
            .HasColumnType("INT")
            .IsRequired();

        Property(x => x.CodigoUsuario).HasColumnName("ID_USUARIO_ACESSO_LOG")
            .HasColumnType("INT")
            .IsRequired();

        HasRequired(x => x.Usuario)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CodigoUsuario)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        Property(x => x.Horario).HasColumnName("HORARIO_ACESSO_LOG")
            .HasColumnType("DATETIME")
            .IsRequired();

        Property(x => x.IP).HasColumnName("IP_ACESSO_LOG")
            .HasColumnType("VARCHAR")
            .HasMaxLength(180)
            .IsRequired();
    }
```

Note that HasKey determines Codigo as the Primary Key and there is no DataAnnotation in the model.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
 Id_Registro = entry.State == EntityState.Added ? null : ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.Entity).EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value.ToString()
```

Comment: This throw a NullReferenceException. EntityKeyValues is null. I added my model and mapping to the description, maybe it helps.